# Move bytewise through class members

Tags: c#

I have written the following class declaration:

```
class MyCommand
{
        public byte Destination;
        public byte Source;
        public byte Cmd;
        public byte Seq;
        public UInt16 Length;
        public byte[] Data;
        public UInt16 Crc;
        public byte Eop;
}
```

Now I want to iterate over all members and check if they have the value *0xED*. For the *UInt16* types I need to compare the low byte first and then the high byte.

Is there a way to achieve this without "manually" checking every single member?

Comment: have u tried anything?

Comment: Technically, you can use *Reflection*, but it's an overshoot in the context.